# Qt Creator 4.1 generated Xcode project linking error

Tags: qt-creator, xcode8

I have an Xcode project for an iOS app (generated by qtcreator 4.1) which does not pass the linking stage in Xcode 8. The error doesn't seem quite serious but I can't find a fix till now, does anyone already fixed this one?

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/copypng failed with exit code 255

it seems to be related to a png file called Default-568h@2x.png.

Thanks in advance!